# jdbc connection TNS:listener

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
package com.jay.controller;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class Dao {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String USER = "SYSTEM";
            String PASS = "admin";
            //jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:@<database>
            //String dbUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:TEST";
            String dbUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:SYSTEM"; //(oracle:  dbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:8081:system)(mysql:   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test)
            String dbClass = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"; // (oracle :oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)( mysql:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)
            String query = "Select * FROM transaction_flow";//transaction_flow
            try {
            Class.forName(dbClass);//for (oracle: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver) (mysql: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)

            //Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl,USER,PASS);//"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:1521/XE","system","sy‌​stem"
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl,USER,PASS);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            for(int i=0;i<1500;i++){
                //stmt.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
              }
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
            int count=0;

            /*  
                while (rs.next()) {
            dbtime = rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println(++count+ ": "+" Message_ID:"+rs.getString("Message_ID")+ "HIB_End_Time:"+rs.getString("HIB_End_Time") + "HIB_Start_Time:"+rs.getString("HIB_Start_Time")
                    +"Gateway_End_Time: "+rs.getString("Gateway_End_Time")+ "Gateway_Start_Time"+ rs.getString("Gateway_Start_Time")+"Response_Message_ID :"+rs.getString("Response_Message_ID")
                    +"Service_Name: " +rs.getString("Service_Name")+ "Service_Version"+ rs.getString("Service_Version")+"Response_URL:"+rs.getString("Response_URL")+"SLA: "+rs.getString("SLA")
                    +"TransactionID: "+rs.getString("TransactionID")+"Originating_System:"+rs.getString("Originating_System")+"Sending_System:"+rs.getString("Sending_System")
                    +"Sequence_ID"+rs.getString("Sequence_ID")+"Operation"+rs.getString("Operation")+"GID_Assigner"+rs.getString("GID_Assigner")+"GID"+rs.getString("GID")
                    +"Sending_Organizaion:"+rs.getString("Sending_Organizaion")+"Sending_User"+rs.getString("Sending_User")+"isAsynchronous"+rs.getBoolean("isAsynchronous")
                    +"DeliveryMethod:" +rs.getString("DeliveryMethod")+"ResponceDeliveryEndpoint: "+rs.getString("ResponceDeliveryEndpoint")+"Consumer_Message_ID"+rs.getString("Consumer_Message_ID")
                    +"eHealth_Transaction_ID"+rs.getString("eHealth_Transaction_ID")+" LOB_Repository_ID: "+rs.getString("LOB_Repository_ID"));

                }

                */ 
            JsonConverter json1=new JsonConverter();
            json1.convertToJson(rs);
            con.close();
            System.out.println("connection is ok");
            } //end try

            catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        //      System.out.println("all data are printed to console..");

    }
}
```

I am getting following error message

java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at com.jay.controller.Dao.main(Dao.java:26)
```

Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

```
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
... 7 more
```

Please help me with this..

Answer (score 0):

I am guess that name of databe is not "SYSTEM".

Url syntax you can see here: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC

Comment: SQL>show parameter service_names - the output will lead you to the answer jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/SERVICE_NAME

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution for this issue.
With the help of following query 
"SELECT username, privilege FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS;"
 I found out that I was using wrong userName.
After rectifying that, the problem is resolved..
:)